# Prevent MVC from serving static files like .js, .css, etc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, security, iis

I have built a web application using MVC5 and just got a pentest result from ITSec department. I was told not to serve static files like .js, .css, .html, images file, etc. For example : someone hit my website with `www.mywebsite.com/Scripts/myjs.js`, it will show the content of the file.

I look around and find that people are suggesting the `route.Ignores` but no luck. So my question :

1. How to achieve this?
2. Is there any real security risk? (the document I got from ITSec dept is marked as Low risk)

Comment: But if you disallow navigating those urls... how do you expect the browser to reach them when necessary?

Comment: Even if somebody loads your page normally, their browser's dev tools will still let them read your JS and CSS. If users being able to see your JS is a security risk then you need to redesign your site to not use JS.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi you should put static files in minified form on external CDN and refer to them properly. Indeed in most of the cases such files are served directly from the site and there is no real reason to prevent access to such files.

Comment: mate, it's impossible preventing the end user to see your js/css files, unless you don't allow them to visit you site

Comment: "Low risk" as in "your site simply stop working". No risk at all :) You may as well return 404 for every Url and be done with it - really secure.

Comment: @KevinSimple: I was looking at something like user can still load js and css in minified form (I minified and bundled everything), but not if they are trying to access the file directly using directory path. Is this possible?

Comment: If you minify and/or bundle the files then you don't deploy the original files so the originals don't have a URL and aren't accessible. But the minified version will have a URL.  And the user can still read the minified version via the browser's dev tools.

Comment: At this point I'd be wondering about the competence of the pen testers. Almost every site in the world will serve static js/css file. minifying them just saves download time. it's not a security thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mate, Short answer is No, you can NOT stop user to check/see your css/js files, that's just simply impossible. Because the browser need to see your css/js file for rendering html, even you hide them somehow in routeing, user still could see them through browser easily.

Css/Js files should not contain sensitive/confidential information anyway, it's just should be how the web page behave and looks like, nothing should be with your business logic, at this point, exposing css/js file to public should be no risk.

Comment: Looking into n-tier architecture might help explain issues surrounding layers and security risks, you could always add that to your answer =)

Comment: unlucky, I don't like architecture from theory perspective, I think most problems comes when people don't understand what they doing, what they want, just simple as that